Pipe a (n)vim command to a bash command
I would like to process in a shell script the output of a neovim command such as echo &runtimepath. I found an online answer here suggesting to use:
nvim --headless --cmd 'echo &runtimepath' --cmd quit

But piping this command to a file with > runtimepath.txt, doesn't put there anything, and the terminal shows the &runtimepath contents, and doesn't pipe it to stdout. Why is that?
I'd like to do the following:
nvim --headless --cmd 'echo &runtimepath' --cmd quit | sed 's/,/\n/g' | while read p; do
  ; # ...
done

Bonus: Write an equivalent command for vim (which doesn't have a --headless argument).

Thanks @filbranden why not post an answer? I can post it myself but I don't want to steel your reputation :).

Done, thanks for confirming this is what you needed!

Output is going to stderr, not stdout, so you need to redirect street instead of stdout to capture it.
For example:
nvim --headless --cmd 'echo &runtimepath' --cmd quit 2>runtimepath.txt

Or:
nvim --headless --cmd 'echo &runtimepath' --cmd quit 2>&1 | grep --color nvim

And your specific case:
nvim --headless --cmd 'echo &runtimepath' --cmd quit 2>&1 | sed 's/,/\n/g' | while read p; do
  ; # ...
done

